# How do i display a button that is selected with two options?

Tags: forms, buttons

[image]

Industry Experience has both a Target Value and an actual value (what the person scored)

Attached is an example where the actual value is not the target value.

How should it be displayed when the actual value IS the target value?

Would i list the Actual and Target on top of eachother? How would i represent the colour of the button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem here is the design itself**

Besides the problem you have encountered, this design is just plain confusing, and it requires a lot of effort to look at and figure out what the actual and target levels are, since they aren't always in the same place.

**Instead of displaying all five levels, only display two boxes, in two columns: the target value and the actual value.**

Use the colors to visually illustrate the five experience levels, rather than whether the target is being met.

With some of the space saved, you would also be able to add an extra visual indicator of whether the target is met (such as a green check mark).  You could even have multiple indicators that highlight someone who exceeds the experience required.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should separate the target and the actual pointers to make it more clear? 
Sometimes (I for one) spend far too much time trying to do things too minimalistically - as in this case; get two values to show up on the same area instead of just separating them...

[image]